# regex to find number of specific length, but with any character except a number before or after it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to work out a regex pattern to search a string for a 12 digit number. The number could have any number of other characters (but not numbers) in front or behind the one I am looking for.

So far I have `/([0-9]{12})/` which finds 12 digit numbers correctly, however it also will match on a 13 digit number in the string.

the pattern should match `123456789012` on the following strings

- "rgergiu123456789012ergewrg"
- "123456789012"
- "#123456789012"
- "ergerg ergerwg erwgewrg \n rgergewrgrewg regewrge 123456789012 ergwerg"

it should match nothing on these strings:

- "123456789012000"
- "egjkrgkergr 123123456789012"

Comment: http://regexpal.com can help you test regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are look-arounds. Something like:

```
/(?<![0-9])[0-9]{12}(?![0-9])/
```

A lookahead or lookbehind matches if the pattern is preceded or followed by another pattern, without consuming that pattern. So this pattern will match 12 digits only if they are not preceded or followed by more digits, without consuming the characters before and after the numbers.

Comment: Heh, thanks for the edit. I wasn't paying as much attention as I should have been :p

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the explanation, regex is only starting to look less like black magic for me :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`/\D(\d{12})\D/` (in which case, the number will be capture index 1)</strike>

Edit: Whoops, that one doesn't work, if the number is the entire string. Use the one below instead

Or, with negative look-behind and look-ahead: `/(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)/` (where the number will be capture index 0)

---

```
if( preg_match("/(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)/", $string, $matches) ) {
    $number = $matches[0];
    # ....
}
```

where `$string` is the text you're testing

Comment: is there any benefit in the difference between \d and [0-9] ? If they are pretty much synonyms I personally think [0-9] is a little more readable

Comment: They are just synonyms. `\d` means "digit" and `\D` means "not digit" so they are mnemonic and relatively easy to remember. But apart from making your expression shorter, there is no advantage.

Comment: @ZakHenry They're the same, but I'm used to `\d` and personally find it more readable because it's two characters rather than five. :-)